# Change product price with AJAX, Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with a custom product where customers can type their custom text that will be added to cart. 
Depending on the size of the text, a different price will be set, the logic is done and I can see the new price in the product object.

It seems that I can change the product object with the new price but I get status 500 back from admin-ajax.php when I do $woocommerce->setup_product_data($product_id).

I have found several topics but none of them seems to work in my case.
I'm not able to update the cart with the new price.

**Here is my ajax function in functions.php:**

```
// Adjust new price
function applyNewPrice() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // From JS
    $product_id = (int) $_POST['id']; 
    // From JS
    $price = (float) $_POST['price'];
    $product_data = get_post($product_id);
    // Code returning status 500 here...
    $product = $woocommerce->setup_product_data($product_data); 
    $product->set_price($price);

    update_post_meta($product_id,'_price',$price);
    update_post_meta($product_id,'_regular_price',$price);

    $woocommerce->clear_product_transients( $product_id );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_applyNewPrice', 'applyNewPrice');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_applyNewPrice', 'applyNewPrice');
```

Comment: How did resolve this? I can't update the price with `set_price` either.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to call does not exist. This is the function you need.

```
$product = wc_setup_product_data( $product_id );
```

No sure where you are coming up with those functions. I could not find this function either?

```
$woocommerce->clear_product_transients( $product_id );
```